# JPA: many-to-many relationship with @JoinTable having the same column for each side of relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, entities, join

I would like to have a JoinTable between 2 entities, this two entities are derived from the same owner entity. So when joining this entities using @ManyToMany relationship I have got @JoinTable (like in below DDL):

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `local_services`.`service_provided_on` (
  `provider_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `service_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `service_point_no` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `work_station_no` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`provider_id`, `service_id`, `service_point_no`, `work_station_no`),
  INDEX `fk_provider_service_has_work_station_work_station1_idx` (`service_point_no` ASC, `work_station_no` ASC, `provider_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_provider_service_has_work_station_provider_service1_idx` (`provider_id` ASC, `service_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_service_provided_on_provider_service`
    FOREIGN KEY (`provider_id` , `service_id`)
    REFERENCES `local_services`.`provider_service` (`provider_id` , `service_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_service_provided_work_station`
    FOREIGN KEY (`service_point_no` , `work_station_no` , `provider_id`)
    REFERENCES `local_services`.`work_station` (`service_point_no` , `work_station_no` , `provider_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

As you can see there are 2 Foreign Keys and each of them is using the same provider_id column. I would like to define using this @JoinTable, Services provided by given Provider on belonging to it WorkPlace (WorkStation). It will be obvious that service provided by provider with id ex. 5 can be only provided on workplace belonging to provider with id 5. So the best will be to share this @JoinColumn between each ForeignKeys. And when trying for example inserting workplace/service with not matching provider id to raise some exception!

I try to do something like this:

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "service_provided_on",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id", referencedColumnName = "provider_id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIGINT UNSIGNED"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "service_id", referencedColumnName = "service_id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT UNSIGNED")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id", referencedColumnName = "provider_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "service_point_no", referencedColumnName = "service_point_no", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT UNSIGNED"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "work_station_no", referencedColumnName = "work_station_no", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT UNSIGNED")
            }
    )
```

But it obviously doesn't work and raise exception like this:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: pl.salonea.entities.WorkStation.providedServices column: provider_id"}}
```

I consider renaming for one foreign key this provider_id ex. work_station_provider_id but then I will be allowed to insert not matching provider_ids and maybe I could define some CONSTRAINT to block such behaviour (how to define this in JPA?). It can work but I will have redundant column with the same provider_id

Answer (score 0):

In some ways, mapping your model this way does not quite make sense. There is nothing in your many-to-many relationship that guarantees that the `Service`s and `Location`s in the relationship must have the same `Provider`. I would change your object model to make that requirement explicit. Add a one-to-many relationship between `Provider` and a new object `ServiceProvidedOn` (not the greatest name; maybe something like `ServiceOccurrence`?). So `Provider` would have a collection attribute `serviceProvidedOns`; and the new class `ServiceProvidedOn` would have three attributes `provider`, `service`, and `workStation` (mapped appropriately). The primary key for `ServiceProvidedOn` would be derived from the three other objects (`Provider`, `Service`, and `WorkStation`).

[I have made a number of assumptions about your model; so I hope this suggestion makes sense.]